# Why pop-up window is not working in Linux side?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a program for finding non sequence orders while scanning and if the non sequence work order found then this will pop up one small window and alert user for whether accept or reject further scanning. The issue here is this program is working in window server very well but not working in Linux server. Let me share the program.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE OERROR          AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lpc_valid       AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE opi_ExpectedSeq AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iCurrentSeq     AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iPrevscandSeq   AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cMessageTxt     AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
       iPrevscandSeq = 20
      iCurrentSeq = 22.


IF iCurrentSeq NE (iPrevscandSeq + 1) THEN DO:

            cMessageTxt = "Current WO Seq : " + STRING(iCurrentSeq) + " EXPECTED SEQ : " + STRING(iPrevscandSeq + 1).

            MESSAGE cMessageTxt 
            VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX QUESTION BUTTONS YES-NO-CANCEL
            TITLE 'Wrong WO Seq'UPDATE lChoice AS LOGICAL.

            CASE lChoice:
                WHEN FALSE THEN DO:
                    ASSIGN
                    OERROR                   = "User Rejected For Non Sequence WO- Current Seq -"
                    lpc_valid                = FALSE.
                END.
            END.
       END.
```

Comment: How do you run the program on Linux? Just putting your code in a Linux Progress editor works for me. OE11.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually this program is written in one plipp file and the file is  calling by one window and that window is running in one application. The databases also running is linux side.(Application->calling window->calling plipp file->calling program for message)

Comment: I don't know whata "plipp" file is so I'm afrait I cannot help with that. Messages do work on Linux so something is wrong here. Maybe the output is diverted somewhere else?

Comment: plipp means the file which has one definition,main,function block and multiple procedures. The main problem is its automatically went lChoice:FLASE without showing messages to the user whether accept or not.

Comment: Your test conditions make it so that it will fire.  Which is exactly what it does.  The problem that you now seem to want solved apparently has something to do with other conditions that are not part of the test code being shared.  If you want meaningful help you need to ask the actual question that you need help with and post code the demonstrates the problem that you are really experiencing.

Comment: On the bright side this example does at least actually compile and run.  Which is a nice improvement,